# Generate R.java Using AAPT

Tags: android, adb, aapt

I am trying to generate apk file using command prompt by following below blog.

[Generate APK using command prompt](http://pavan2pyati.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-apk-generation-through-command.html)

I successfully generated **key**, but when i am trying to generate **R.java**  it is giving following error

Command i used to generate R.java:-

```
E:\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\19.0.0>aapt com.concep
t.build -v -f -m -S E:\AppBuilder\res -J E:\AppBuilder\gen -M E:\AppBuilder\Andr
oidManifest.xml -I E:\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platforms\andro
id-19\android.jar
```

Error:-

```
**Crunching PNG Files in source dir: E:\AppBuilder\res
To destination dir: (null)**
```

Please tell me what wrong i am doing .

OR 
Can Please  help me how to generate apk using command prompt.